# Is there a way to maximize a NetMeeting shared screen on a second, larger monitor?

Tags: netmeeting

My primary monitor is 1280x800, and my secondary monitor is 1280*1024.  When somebody shares their screen in NetMeeting, it'd be nice to be able to drag the shared screen onto my larger monitor and maximize it.  But, NetMeeting seems to limit the window size to the resolution of my primary monitor.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe NetMeeting is actually sizing the window to the originator's screen size.  You can move the NetMeeting window to your other monitor, but you'll only be able to see a screen as large as they have their screen resolution set.

Answer (score 0):

I am a training instructor for a major telecommunications company and I use net meeting to share my desktop with the students. Since the desktop I'm using and their PCs are the same size and screen resolution, usually a scroll bar is at the top and sides of the window. If one selects ALT & Enter at the same time, the window will maiximize and the scroll bar will not be needed. Make sure they maiximize the window that being shared first then select ALT & Enter at the same time.